# get DIV id from coordinates

Tags: jquery, css

as an example I have the following code which displays 3 div boxes per row with many rows on my page

```
      <div id='row1col1' class='duty' style="top:50px ; left:50px " ></div>
      <div id='row1col2' class='duty' style="top:50px ; left:150px " ></div>
      <div id='row1col3' class='duty' style="top:50px ; left:250px " ></div>
      <div id='row2col1' class='duty' style="top:150px ; left:50px " ></div>
      <div id='row2col2' class='duty' style="top:150px ; left:150px " ></div>
      <div id='row2col2' class='duty' style="top:150px ; left:250px " ></div>
      <div id='row3col1' class='duty' style="top:250px ; left:50px " ></div>
      <div id='row3col2' class='duty' style="top:250px ; left:150px " ></div>
      etc
```

What I want to do is dynamically place a new div and alter it depending on the id or other attribute of the div immediately above it, I dont think this would be the parent so is there any way I can get this data ? As I would know the 'top' and 'left' position would I be able to get the ID of a div this way ?

Any help please ?

Comment: I imagine that you'd have to map the IDs to their relative co-ordinates on page load, and then perform a check on that array when adding new elements.

Comment: Will you be controlling the ID's for all divs?

Comment: Getting the element based on coordinates is certainly possible, but it's inefficient and never really needed, as there are so many other better ways to do it.

Comment: I am assuming all these have position:absolute, and that the new div you're inserting is also position:absolute. Is this correct?

Comment: Mark - yes I am controlling the IDs and position is absolute

Comment: When you say "above", do you mean on the Y axis, or on the Z axis?

Comment: its the Y axis , each box represents a day , if my event is for example 3 days long I want to increase the height of the div rather then represent 3 days with 3 boxes, hope this makes sense ?

Comment: I'm betting that there is a more efficient way to keep track of how many days long the event is, but I've posted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely a better way to accomplish your goal. However, this function will do what I think you're wanting:

```
function findAbove(selector, x, y) {
    var maxpos = 0, maxel;
    jQuery(selector).each(function(i, el) {
        var $el = jQuery(el),
            ex = parseInt($el.css('left')),
            ey = parseInt($el.css('top'));
        if (ex < x && ey < y && ex + ey > maxpos) {
            maxpos = ex + ey;
            maxel = $el;
        }
    });
    return maxel;
}
// Pass the coordinates of the new div
findAbove('.duty', 250, 250).css('border','2px solid green');
```

If you know that your new div will be perfectly aligned with the divs above it, then you should change `ex < x` to `ex == x`, and change `ex + ey` (both times) to `ey`.